# Laravel Auth , login doesn't work. It always return false?

Tags: authentication, laravel

I'm trying to make an Auth and Login application with Laravel but it always fails.
I always see "Username or password incorrect." in login.blade.php

My files are like theese ;

route.php

```
    Route::get('login' , function() {    
       return View::make('auth.login');
    });

    Route::post('logincontrol', function() {

        $userdata = array(
            'username'      => Input::get('username'),
            'password'      => Input::get('password') 
        );

        if ( Auth::attempt($userdata) )
        {
            return Redirect::to('auth.dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('login')
                ->with('login_errors', true);
        }

    });



    Route::get('dashboard', function(){  

        echo 'welcome';
    });

       Route::get('insert', function() {

           DB::table('users')->insert(array(
          'username'  => 'admin',
          'password'  => Hash::make('admin')
          ));

   });
```

login.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open( array('url' => 'logincontrol') ) }}

    <!-- check for login errors flash var -->
    @if (Session::has('login_errors'))
        <span class="error">Username or password incorrect.</span>
    @endif

    <!-- username field -->
    <p>{{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}</p>
    <p>{{ Form::text('username') }}</p>

    <!-- password field -->
    <p>{{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}</p>
    <p>{{ Form::password('password') }}</p>

    <!-- submit button -->
    <p>{{ Form::submit('Login') }}</p>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

First of all, i run the  insert URL  and added admin to my db.

Then  i run /login URL form is shown.  I enter username and password like in insert Route, but i always turn false.

i took the codes from http://codehappy.daylerees.com/authentication , i read all of the page but i could not do it .

Edit : I tried ;

```
'password'      => Hash::make( Input::get('password') )
```

But it didn't work :(

Edit: my auth.php file is like this.

```
return array(

    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'username'=>'username', 
    'model' => 'User', 
    'table' => 'users',
    'reminder' => array(

        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

        'table' => 'password_reminders',

        'expire' => 60,

    ),

);
```

Comment: Do you get the message "Username or password incorrect." ? Or anything else happens?

Comment: Can you see the user in the database? Is the password hashed? It must be something very like this: `$2y$10$DkhQ9P85b6Qdv31kO5/NtOo4C5n0tndpg.b2FqN7zXM3pfqHh6T0y`.

Comment: yes , I can see the password in db. its hashed like you said.

But i found somethind interesting. I run the  /insert URL and added username and password to db again. it added a different value.

And i run the command Hash::make('admin') ,

it always returns a different hashed value.

i think its the problem, but i don't know how to solve it :(

Comment: That's right, they won't be the same ever, this are the hashing functions doing good work. Looks like Sheikh Heera has a good answer.

Comment: but when i tried like this in URL  /test 
    $u = DB::table('users')->where('username','=','admin')->get();
    $pass =  $u[0]->password;
    var_dump( Hash::check( $pass, Hash::make('admin') ) );

its returning false

Answer (score 1):

The Hash that is always changing is normal because the Hash::check()'ing process uses the salt embedded in the hash to compare the plain text value.
for more information about this look here
http://laravel.io/topic/20/hashing-in-laravel and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

I've stumbled upon your question because I'm having the exact error...

I'm recommending you to watch this [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/lessons/auth-essentials) by Jeffrey Way about Authentication. If I find something I'll let you know because I'm also struggling with this problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration for `authentication` could be found in `application/config/auth.php` and in this file, there is a setting for the the `username` like

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the database column that should be considered the
| "username" for your users. Typically, this will either be "username"
| or "email". Of course, you're free to change the value to anything.
|
*/
```

By default it's

```
'username' => 'email',
```

In your case, it's `username` because you have

```
DB::table('users')->insert(array(
    'username'  => 'admin', // looks like you are using username for login
    'password'  => Hash::make('admin')
));
```

And following code for login

```
$userdata = array(
    'username'      => Input::get('username'), // you are using username field
    'password'      => Input::get('password') 
);

// Login
if ( Auth::attempt($userdata) )
{
    //...
}
```

So, if you didn't change it in the `application/config/auth.php` file then you should change it to

```
'username' => 'username',
```

Alternatively you can us an `email` field in your table and authenticate using `email` field instead of `username`. BTW, this is related to `Laravel-3` according to your [given link](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/authentication) in the question.

Comment: i changed it like you said.
but the problem is still continueing.
i editted the question.

Comment: @AshleyLashley, Also, Make sure `password` field's length is not too short, can you change the length of the password field too `100` and then delete old record and insert a new record and then try to login again.

Comment: At first i thought that was the problem , i had changed it varchar(255) but the problem is still contineing .

Comment: @AshleyLashley, If you did everything according to the article you've mentioned then please review the whole process again and delete old records and add new records, maybe using different username and password (more than one) and try to login.

Comment: it's my third time doing the article, i couldn't understand where am i wrong :S

Comment: @AshleyLashley, then you should leave it for now, take a break and then restart it from the beginning, just a debugging tip/technique.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is the simple things that get you.
I spend a large part of today with a similar issue and the solution in my case was that I am using artisan generate:scaffold which had created the user model with;

`class User extends Eloquent`

I modified this model by adding

`implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface`

and then added the following missing functions:

```
/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()

{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
```

Everything works just fine for me now. Hope this helps you.

ossi